# Accessing search Params from Layout or Component File in Next.JS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to access the search params in a Component or in Layout File to get the lang. There is an way to do that? I Read that is impossible to get the searchparams in Layout File, but there is any other way in Next.JS 13? Or other way to get the lang inside the component?

```
export default function DashboardLayout({ children }: DashboardProps) {
    return (
        <html>
            <body>
                <div className="w-full h-full flex absolute bg-slate-100">
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <div className="bg-sky-800 w-[20rem] h-12 flex items-center justify-center">
                            <img src="/bigLogo.svg" className="w-28 h-12" title="ProPay" alt="ProPay" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-white h-full shadow-md">
                            <DashboardMenu />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
                        <div className="bg-sky-700 flex justify-between items-center h-12 pr-5">
                            <p className="ml-5 text-lg text-white">Câmara Municipal de Tondela</p>
                            <SelectLang />
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-3">
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
};
```

.

```
export default function DashboardMenu(){
    const lang: DashboardLangsTypes = getLang("en", "dashboard"); // i want the lang here
    return (
...
```

Comment: Did you find a solution because I Look into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

This is not documented but the Layout component actually receives 2 properties `children` and `params`, so you can simply read the params property

```
interface DashboardProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { id: string }
}

export default function DashboardLayout({ children, params }: DashboardProps) {
  console.log(params.id)
  ...
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts)

> Layouts are Server Components by default but can be set to a Client Component.

So it's technically possible to read the params using the **Client Component** hook [`useParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params). I would not recommend using it as you will need to transform your Layout Component into a Client Component (with the `use client` directive).

Answer (score 1):

you can use router to get the lang  as parameter and then pass it down as props to your components

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const lang = router.query.lang;
```

to import it :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

in your case :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function DashboardLayout({ children }: DashboardProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const lang = router.query.lang;

  return (
    ....
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for try to help. I receive this error, but i don't want to render this at client. ReactServerComponentsError:

You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry "use client":
  ./src\app\dashboard\layout.tsx  The next/navigation don't have useRouter() query

Comment: okay let me get this clear you want to pass the lang from DashboardLayout to DashboardMenu component ?

Comment: The lang is in the url, if I can get it from the Layout or directly from the component, whatever. Because I easily send the layout data to the component. I just want to access data in the url.

Comment: i will add another answer so it is more clear

Comment: Note that this will only work for client-side components

Answer (score 0):

Helo, if you gonna use a client side component then you can use **useSearchParams** Hook available in the version 13..

[Here is the beta documentation link](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params#updating-searchparams)

```
'use client';

export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()!;

  // Get a new searchParams string by merging the current
  // searchParams with a provided key/value pair
  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
      params.set(name, value);

      return params.toString();
    },
    [searchParams],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <p>Sort By</p>

      {/* using useRouter */}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // <pathname>?sort=asc
          router.push(pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'asc'));
        }}
      >
        ASC
      </button>

      {/* using <Link> */}
      <Link
        href={
          // <pathname>?sort=desc
          pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'desc')
        }
      >
        DESC
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use the useParams hooks exported from next/navigation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).