# Accessing search Params from Sever Side Layout File in Next.JS 13 (App Router)

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13, urlsearchparams

I need to access searchParams named promo on layout file which is server side rendered?
Is it really impossible to access search params in server side rendered layout file?

layout.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs"
import { getUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions"

const DashBoardLayout = async ({ children, searchParams }: { children: React.ReactNode, searchParams: { promo: string } }) => {

  // searchParams is Undefined, but works on other server components (page.tsx), but not on layout.tsx
  console.log(searchParams)

  const user = await currentUser()
  if (!user) redirect(`/sign-in?promo=${searchParams?.promo}`)
  const userInfo = await getUser(user.id)
  if (!userInfo) redirect(`/onboarding?promo=${searchParams?.promo}`)


  return <>{children}</>
}

export default DashBoardLayout
```

works on normal page.tsx

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import { getCourses } from "@/lib/actions/course.actions"

const page = async ({searchParams}: {searchParams: {promo: string}}) => {
  const courses = await getCourses()
  if (!courses || !courses.length) {
    redirect("/create-course")
  }
  const courseId = courses[0].id
  console.log(searchParams.promo)
  redirect(`/purchase/${courseId}?promo=${searchParams.promo}`)
  return <div>page</div>
}

export default page
```

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861004/accessing-search-params-from-layout-or-component-file-in-next-js-13), but it didn't mention for server components, especially for layout files, It would only work for page.tsx files.

Question states it's impossible, I need some alernative to access SearchParams in server-side rendered layout.tsx

Answer (score 1):

SearchParams is not accessible on layout layer.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#params-optional

> searchParams is a Dynamic API whose values cannot be known ahead of
> time. Using it will opt the page into dynamic rendering at request
> time.

```
 if (!user) redirect(`/sign-in?promo=${searchParams?.promo}`)
  const userInfo = await getUser(user.id)
  if (!userInfo) redirect(`/onboarding?promo=${searchParams?.promo}`)
```

Anyway, Is there any reasons you're doing this especially on layout?

If you just want to redirect users before page rendering, I'd rather redirect users with middleware because functions on middleware are executed before rendering.

Comment: I am using this to pass the query params when redirecting, I thought of doing it once on layout.tsx file would be efficient and would reduce repetition rather than calling it under every page.tsx file under this route. But it seems, it's not possible. I will try using middleware.

Comment: This seems to be the link: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#layouts-do-not-receive-searchparams